# Mapping web templates inside asp.net mvc Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, orchardcms

I want to build a new web site for a construction company. so i find some powerful web templates that support the same business area, such as :-

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53844.html

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52718.html

now as i am a web developer i can easily update these templates to contain our content. but i need to have a CMS to allow non-IT users to edit the web site. so after doing some search i settle on using Orchard CMS ,, but i need some help in answering these questions:-

- i think the main challenge in my case will be to map these web templates inside Orchard.. mainly to modify the web template layout to be Orchard compatible.so my first question is if it supported to have these general web templates to work with Orchard CMS?
- second question ,, will there be some limitations when mapping web templetes to be managed inside Orchard CMS.. for example will some UI components stop working?
- can some one provide links on how to map web templates inside Orachrd?
- since Orchard is based on asp.net mvc. now if i create a new asp.net mvc5 web application, i can easily have these web templates mapped inside my project . this includes modifying the asp.net mvc `_layout` view and adding the related css & JavaScript.. so is the process to map a web template inside Orcahrd similar to the process of mapping a web template inside a standard asp.net mvc web application ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1. Sure. People do that all the time.
2. What do you mean? What components specifically?
3. Use shape tracing.
4. Yes, see 3.

Comment: i think he means non-it users. so shape tracing might be a bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to 1.9. It has this new Templates for pages. SO you could create templates with elements already placed and then users can customise them with data.

You can do it with Widgets too, but requires a bit more admin knowledge... not much.

You could also create a module to hide any functionality behind an as-simple-as-needed UI.

start here: [Orchard Docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/).

If you are a web developer, start looking at the code and after you get all the Orchard 'aaaahhh' moments, you'll be alright.